# SNAPSHOT mode of Feature Layer in ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.x

Tags: feature-layer, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there any posibility to set Feature Layer in "SNAPSHOT mode", as it was in ArcGIS JS API 3.x?
The main goal is to fetch features once to the client and avoid additional queries at each map pan/zoom for those layers which are static by their nature and have not many features.

Answer (score 1):

According to the following documentation - https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/functionality-matrix/#featurelayer. Modes are not planned for JS API 4.X.